# Mongodb 3.0 java insertOne

Tags: java, mongodb, crud

I'm trying to upgrade my legacy application from Java driver 2.10.1 into 3.0.0
So the insert method is changed into insertOne. but `DBCollection.insert()` returned the result, where I can check the `getError()`. But `MongoCollection.insertOne()` does not return a value.

How to check an error of operation?

Answer (score 3):

You have to catch:

- MongoWriteException - if the write failed due some other failure specific to the insert command
- MongoWriteConcernException - if the write failed due being unable to fulfil the write concern
- MongoException - if the write failed due some other failure

more info here: http://api.mongodb.org/java/current/com/mongodb/client/MongoCollection.html#insertOne-TDocument-